# Spacy - Tokenize quoted string

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy 2.0 and using a quoted string as input.

Example string

```
"The quoted text 'AA XX' should be tokenized"
```

and expecting to extract

```
[The, quoted, text, 'AA XX', should, be, tokenized]
```

I however get some strange results while experimenting.  Noun chunks and ents looses one of the quote.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
s = "The quoted text 'AA XX' should be tokenized"
doc = nlp(s)
print([t for t in doc])
print([t for t in doc.noun_chunks])
print([t for t in doc.ents])
```

Result

```
[The, quoted, text, ', AA, XX, ', should, be, tokenized]
[The quoted text 'AA XX]
[AA XX']
```

What is the best way to address what I need

Comment: Try: https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#tokenizer-exceptions

Comment: Note that the docs say - "Keep in mind that generating exceptions only makes sense if there's a clearly defined and finite number of them,"   I want to have something generic and still keeping all existing features of tokenizer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While you *could* modify the tokenizer and add your own custom prefix, suffix and infix rules that exclude quotes, I'm not sure this is the best solution here.

For your use case, it might make more sense to add a [component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) to your pipeline that merges (certain) quoted strings into one token before the tagger, parser and entity recognizer are called. To accomplish this, you can use the [rule-based `Matcher`](http://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#rule-based-matching) and find combinations of tokens surrounded by `'`. The following pattern looks for one or more alphanumeric characters:

```
pattern = [{'ORTH': "'"}, {'IS_ALPHA': True, 'OP': '+'}, {'ORTH': "'"}]
```

[Here's a visual example](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=The%20quoted%20text%20%27AA%20XX%27%20should%20be%20tokenized&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ORTH%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%27%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A3%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2B%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22IS_ALPHA%22%2C%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A4%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ORTH%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%27%22%7D%5D%7D%5D) of the pattern in the interactive matcher demo. To do the merging, you can then set up the `Matcher`, add the pattern and write a function that takes a `Doc` object, extracts the matched spans and merges them into one token by calling their `.merge` method.

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('QUOTED', None, [{'ORTH': "'"}, {'IS_ALPHA': True, 'OP': '+'}, {'ORTH': "'"}])

def quote_merger(doc):
    # this will be called on the Doc object in the pipeline
    matched_spans = []
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = doc[start:end]
        matched_spans.append(span)
    for span in matched_spans:  # merge into one token after collecting all matches
        span.merge()
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(quote_merger, first=True)  # add it right after the tokenizer
doc = nlp("The quoted text 'AA XX' should be tokenized")
print([token.text for token in doc])
# ['The', 'quoted', 'text', "'AA XX'", 'should', 'be', 'tokenized']
```

For a more elegant solution, you can also refactor the component as a reusable class that sets up the matcher in its `__init__` method ([see the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) for examples).

If you add the component first in the pipeline, all other components like the tagger, parser and entity recognizer will only get to see  the retokenized `Doc`. That's also why you might want to write more specific patterns that only merge certain quoted strings you care about. In your example, the new token boundaries *improve* the predictions – but I can also think of many other cases where they don't, especially if the quoted string is longer and contains a significant part of the sentence.

Comment: This is very helpful.  It should address most of the things I care for now. Thanks a lot for the comprehensive response.

Comment: @Ines thanks for that answer. Could you please talk a bit more about those cases in which you think it will not work? Some examples if possible, please?

Comment: @fersarr Sure! Consider a string like `"He said, 'the text should be tokenized'"` – using the above component, this would now be tokenized as `["He", "said", ",", "'the text should be tokenized'"]`. The single token `"'the text should be tokenized'"` will be pretty useless, and the tagger, parser and entity recognizer  won't be able to make meaningful predictions for that sentence.

Comment: Thank you :) Yea, I think in my case I will have to re-parse the text inside the quotes so that I get both things properly: 1) the event that he said something 2) the details of what he said

Comment: @InesMontani how would you do a rule to match quotes with more than just alphanumeric characters inside? for example """He said "I didn't do it".""" ?

Comment: @InesMontani following up on the above comment, I tried wildcards but it didn't work.

Comment: I added more details here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3196

Comment: @InesMontani is this still supported in Spacy v3.0? I cannot see any reference to the merge method in the Span section of the doc.