# Tokenization not working the same for both case.

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have a document

```
doc = nlp('x-xxmessage-id:')
```

When I want to extract the tokens of this one I get 'x', 'xx', 'message' and 'id', ':'. Everything goes well. 
Then I create a new document

```
test_doc = nlp('id')
```

If I try to extract the tokens of test_doc, I will get 'i' and 'd'. Is there any way to get past this problem? Because I want to get the same token as above and this is creating problems in the text processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like language itself, tokenization is context-dependent and the [language-specific data](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#language-data) defines rules that tell spaCy how to split the text based on the surrounding characters. spaCy's defaults are also optimised for general-purpose text, like news text, web texts and other modern writing.

In your example, you've come across an interesting case: the abstract string `"x-xxmessage-id:"` is split on punctuation, while the isolated lowercase string `"id"` is split into `"i"` and `"d"`, because in written text, it's most commonly an alternate spelling of "I'd" or "i'd" ("I could", "I would" etc.). You can find the respective rules [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/446f5ec41be534758c0bdb81b066b6e5bbd00ca7/spacy/lang/en/tokenizer_exceptions.py#L35).

If you're dealing with specific texts that are substantially different from regular natural language texts, you usually want to [customise the tokenization rules](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers) or possibly even add a [`Language` subclass](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages) for your own custom "dialect". If there's a fixed number of cases you want to tokenize differently that can be expressed by rules, another option would be to add a component to your pipeline that [merges the split tokens back together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752266/spacy-tokenize-quoted-string/50775597#50775597).

Finally, you could also try using the [language-independent `xx` / `MultiLanguage`](https://spacy.io/usage/models#multi-language) class instead. It still includes very basic tokenization rules, like splitting on punctuation, but none of the rules specific to the English language.

```
from spacy.lang.xx import MultiLanguage
nlp = MultiLanguage()
```

Comment: I see. The problem is that my text it's not from one specific category only. Once it might be id like identification, and in another occurrence, it might be id like I would. For the moment I added it as a special case, because anyway even if I get only 'I' I will skip it as a stopword.
For the moment I have added it as a special case: 
special_case = [{ORTH: u'id', LEMMA: u'id', POS: u'NOUN'}]

nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'id', special_case)

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely tricky to solve with rule-based tokenization only. In the upcoming v2.1, the parser will be able to learn to merge tokens. This is mostly intended for languages like Chinese, Japanese, Korean, but might be helpful for your use case, as well. You could then post-train the model with both types of examples, and over-segmented tokens (like `"id"` in the context of "an ID") would be merged automatically.